# C: never getting to return statement

Tags: c

I am implementing a program which hides messages in ppm files and then retrieves them. One of the last things I need to do is to "return 2" if there is a problem opening the file. If I enter a file which can't be opened (file doesn't exist or wrong extension, etc) then it will display the error message on stderr, but for some reason it won't execute the very next line, "return 2"!

It simply then returns 0 instead of returning 2.

```
int load_ppm_image(const char *input_file_name, unsigned char **data, int *n,
               int *width, int *height, int *max_color)
{
    char line[80];
    char c;

    FILE * image_file;
    //image_file = fopen(input_file_name, "rb");

    if (fopen(input_file_name, "rb") == NULL)  // checks to see if file cant be opened
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The input image file could not be opened\n");
        return 2;  // why isn't this being returned???
    }
    else
    {
        image_file = fopen(input_file_name, "rb");
    }

    fscanf(image_file, "%s", line);

    fscanf(image_file, "%d %d", width, height);

    *n = (3 * (*width) * (*height));

    fscanf(image_file, "%d%c", max_color, &c);
    *data = (unsigned char *)malloc((*n)*sizeof(unsigned char));
    size_t m = fread(*data, sizeof(unsigned char), *n, image_file);

    assert(m == *n);
    fclose(image_file);
    return 0;
}

int hide_message(const char *input_file_name, const char *message, const char *output_file_name)
{
    unsigned char * data;
    int n;
    int width;
    int height;
    int max_color;

    n = 3 * width * height;
    int code = load_ppm_image(input_file_name, &data, &n, &width, &height, &max_color);

    if (code)
    {
        // return the appropriate error message if the image doesn't load correctly
        return code;
    }

    int len_message;
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char letter;

    // get the length of the message to be hidden
    len_message = (int)strlen(message);

    for(int j = 0; j < len_message; j++)
    {

        letter = message[j];
        int mask = 0x80;

        // loop through each byte
        for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            if((letter & mask) == 0)
            {
                //set right most bit to 0
                data[count] = 0xfe & data[count];
            }
            else
            {
                //set right most bit to 1
                data[count] = 0x01 | data[count];
            }
            // shift the mask
            mask = mask>>1 ;
            count++;
        }
    }
    // create the null character at the end of the message (00000000)
    for(int b = 0; b < 8; b++){
        data[count] = 0xfe & data[count];
        count++;
    }

    // write a new image file with the message hidden in it
    int code2 = write_ppm_image(output_file_name, data, n, width, height, max_color);

    if (code2)
    {
        // return the appropriate error message if the image doesn't load correctly
        return code2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2 || argv[1][0] != '-')
    {
        // the user didn't enter a switch
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: no switch was entered.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else if ((strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0) && (argc == 5))
    {
        // hides a message in an output file
        hide_message(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);
    }

    else if ((strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0) && (argc == 3))
    {
        // retrieves a hidden message in a given file
        retrieve_message(argv[2]);
    }

    else
    {
        // all other errors prompt a general usage error
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: error");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it going inside that function? Is the print statement working?

Comment: Yes, so the functions will find their way to "fprintf(stderr, "The input image file could not be opened\n");", and print that. But, it won't print the next line.

Comment: What do you mean "won't print the next line"? How exactly are you determining that the `return 2` is not being executed?

Comment: `return` is not supposed to print anything. It returns a value to the calling function. You can check the return value there.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say return 2 instead of print it. When I run the program it prints "The input image file could not be opened\n" and then displays  "Program ended with exit code: 0"

Comment: What does the function calling `hide_message` look like?

Comment: `return` in the `load_ppm_image` function does not exit the program. You need to look at what `main` returns (or any `exit` calls). That is where the exit code comes from. Since you have not shown `main` we can't comment on that directly.

Comment: I just added my main function to the post.

Comment: There are code paths in your `main` which do not return a value. If you want to return the value from `load_ppm_image` then in `main` you should check the return value of `hide_message` and return that value if it is not zero.

Comment: "Program ended with exit code: 0" is the return value of `main`,  not some random function buried in your code

Comment: I just had to say "return hide_message(...)" and "return retrieve_message(...)". That fixed it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Program ended with exit code: 0`

The exit code of a C program is the return value of `main` or the `status` value in an explicit `exit` function call. In your case, the `load_ppm_image` returns a value to its caller function `hide_message` which in turn returns the same value to its caller function `main`. However, `main` does not explicitly return anything for the case that calls `hide_message`. The C standard specifies that `main` implicitly returns 0 if it reaches the end of the function without an explicit return. Hence the exit code of 0 in your case.

To get the behaviour you desire modify your `main` code to return the `hide_message` return value.

```
else if ((strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0) && (argc == 5))
{
    // hides a message in an output file
    return (hide_message(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From code :

In main function you are calling the hide_message function, but not collecting return value of hide_message()

```
hide_message(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);
```

So the main function is ending with return 0.